# Improving performance while sorting a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting

I am sorting an array (`filtered`) containing JS-Objects by their attribute `sortdist`:

```
filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (!a.sortdist) { return 1;}
  else if (!b.sortdist) { return -1;}
  else if (a.sortdist > b.sortdist) { return 1;}
  else { return -1; }
});
```

However, I am sorting 9000 datasets, which takes a really long time. Is there any way to improve the performance of my sorting algorithm?

Comment: What data type is `sortdist`? Can they be equal? What if they are both undefined?

Comment: Is this sort being done on the database, server side, or client side?

Comment: This post might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082425/fastest-way-to-sort-32bit-signed-integer-arrays-in-javascript This guy implemented radix sort that can sort 2 million records. As well, you may want to look into using Typed Arrays (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int32Array).

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I don't know anything about javascript

If you have a construct like

```
if (condition){
   return someValue;
} else { 
   return someOtherValue;
}
```

the `else` can be omited, because if the first condition is `true` the `else` is never reached.

So your code could be refactored to

```
filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (!b.sortdist) { return -1; }
  if (!a.sortdist || a.sortdist > b.sortdist) { return 1; }
  return -1;
});
```

which doesn't improve the performance, but I don't see anything to make your code faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your results can be one of two. You can simplify the code by trying to meet one condition and return the expected result, otherwise, throw up the other result. In this case, your code only returns `1` when:

- `a.sortdist` doesn't exist.
- `a.sortdist > b.sortdist`.

...and `-1` for all others. Thus your code can be simplified as:

```
filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
  return (!a.sortdist || a.sortdist > b.sortdist) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

As for performance, I suppose you could have negligible performance gain because you're not accessing props that much, and you're making the JS run less conditions. But for readability, this one's much more clearer.

Comment: Looks much better! But tested (http://jsperf.com/testswqeqwe) it doesnt really improve the performance.

Comment: @user3351652 Yup, performance gain is negligible. That's because we only removed statements in the sorter. The real bottleneck is the internal algorithm used by `sort`. You can search for custom sort implementations though.